# DB2 not saving stylized apostrophe (’)

Tags: character-encoding, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to insert a stylized apostrophe (’) into a table in DB2 LUW 9.7. Every method I have tried has resulted in it being a square () when selected back.

The methods I have tried to insert it:

- Modifying and committing a row in Control Center (GUI)
- Updating a row via SQL command in Command Editor
- Loading from a file (both UTF-8 encoded and ANSI encoded) through IBM Data Studio 2.2

Is there a way to get this character into the database? If not, is there a list of characters that simply cannot be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the encoding of your database/tablespace? I suspect it needs to be set to UTF-8. You may need to create a new tablespace or recreate the database with the encoding explicitly set to UTF-8.

To [determine the encoding](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/c0004821.htm), run the following command and look for the "Code set" information:

```
db2 get db cfg for <database name>
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Our infrastructure people said that it was using UFT-8 encoding, and I assumed this was true.

Answer (score 1):

from [Inserting an Apostrophe in DB2 table](http://ibmmainframes.com/about41147.html)

```
 insert into userid.empy values(1234,'RAM''');
```

> You have put 2 Single Quotations, for a single quote to appear in the
>   table.

see also:
http://www.ibmmainframes.com/viewtopic.php?t=36901&highlight=apostrophe and
http://www.ibmmainframes.com/viewtopic.php?t=29213&highlight=apostrophe

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the API, a good way is to prepare the statement and bind the quote-containing text to a parameter.

Remind that allowing someone to type in a quote and insert that unchanged (like sprintf(sqlstr, "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('%s')", inputstr);) may lead to an SQL-Injection.

my input:

> test');drop database;insert into mytable values ('test

may lead to an empty database